# Java Runtime.exec() hanging

Tags: java, runtimeexception

I am getting into the Defunct zombie process whenever the below code is executed. Could someone help me to resolve this issue.

```
  private static boolean executeCommand(String command)
        throws ClientException, IOException, InterruptedException {

    int exitVal = 1; // 0 is success, so we default to a nonzero.
    Process proc = null;
    try{
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    proc = rt.exec(command);

    //Below lines are required to flush out the streams. else the process will hang.
    ReadStream s1 = new ReadStream("stdin", proc.getInputStream ());
    ReadStream s2 = new ReadStream("stderr", proc.getErrorStream ());
    s1.start ();
    s2.start ();        

    exitVal = proc.waitFor();

    if (exitVal == 0) {
        return true;
    } else {
        throw new ClientException("103", "" + command + " failed.");
    }
    }finally{
        if(proc  != null){
            proc.destroy();
        }
    }

}
```

I am clearing all the streams in separate threads.

Here is my ReadStream class

```
 public class ReadStream implements Runnable {

private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ReadStream.class);

String name;
InputStream is;
Thread thread;

public ReadStream(String name, InputStream is) {
    this.name = name;
    this.is = is;
}

public void start() {
    thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while (true) {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s == null)
                break;
            logger.info("[" + name + "] " + s);
        }
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Problem reading stream " + name + "... :" + ex);

    }
}
```

}

Comment: what command are you passing?

Comment: What does ReadStream looks like?

Comment: Thanks Dukeling....

Hi, I update the ReadStream in my question. Also, I am using a mv command

Comment: You need to close the process's input stream, which, confusingly, is acquired via `Process.getOutputStream()`, before you call `waitFor()`, and you should only call `Process.destroy()` if `waitFor()` failed.

Comment: Hi EJP, I dint understand what you mean in first line. Could you please write some snippet ?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is the problem but try to change the run methode to:

```
try {
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        do {
            String s = br.readLine();
            if (s != null)
              logger.info("[" + name + "] " + s);
        } while (s != null);
        is.close();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        logger.error("Problem reading stream " + name + "... :" + ex);

    }
```

Comment: Hi, But what do you think is causing the defunct process to be created ? any idea ?

Comment: You should loog in your logger what are you receiving there, as long as you do not get null back its infite loop.